# Start supervisor from staltstack

Tags: supervisord, salt-stack

I am trying to start supervisor in one of my minons. I have a .sls file with the following content:

```
service:
  supervisord.running:
    - require:
      - pkg: supervisor
    - update: True
    - watch:
      - file: /etc/supervisor.conf
```

which results in an error message:

```
      ID: service
Function: supervisord.running
  Result: False
 Comment: service: ERROR (no such process)
 Started: 11:30:18.515925
Duration: 270.551 ms
 Changes:
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Salt takes the state id (the top key you named as `service`) as `name` key for your state. According to [documentation here](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.supervisord.html), state `supervisord.running` uses `name` for "*Service name as defined in the supervisor configuration file*".

I guess you meant something else instead of `service`. In this case just add `name` key explicitly, like this:

```
service:
  supervisord.running:
    - name: PUT_YOUR_CORRECT_SERVICE_NAME_HERE
    - require:
      - pkg: supervisor
    - update: True
    - watch:
      - file: /etc/supervisor.conf
```

Make sure that service name `PUT_YOUR_CORRECT_SERVICE_NAME_HERE` exists in your "*supervisor configuration file*".

I also suggest to change state id to something more specific than `service` as it requires to be globally unique, for example, `supervisor_SERVICE_NAME`:

```
supervisor_SERVICE_NAME:
  supervisord.running:
    # ...
```